# What does this mean "You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyACM1 device!"?

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I have been trying to connect my Nokia E65 phone to my Ubuntu 12.04 via wammu. I tried the option of "Automatically Search The Phone". But I get the error messages like this in the screen:

```
Wammu is now searching for phone:
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS0 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS1 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS2 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS3 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS4 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS5 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS6 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS7 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS8 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS9 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS10 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS11 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS12 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS13 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS14 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS15 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS16 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS17 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS18 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyS19 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyACM0 device!
You don't have permissions for /dev/ttyACM1 device!
Discovering Bluetooth devices using PyBluez
Could not access Bluetooth subsystem (error accessing bluetooth device)
All finished, found 0 phones
No phone has been found!
```

What does this mean? How to overcome this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that your user don't have permissions to access to /dev (devices).

Try: sudo wammu

to gain permissions to access to devices

Another thing you can do is to put your user in bluetooth group system

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 12.04 all serial devices belong to the dialout group. You can quickly verify that by

```
ls -a /dev/ttyS*
```

you should see something like

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 74 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS10
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 75 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS11
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 76 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS12
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 77 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS13
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 78 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS14
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 79 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS15
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 80 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS16
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 81 May 30 18:22 /dev/ttyS17
```

assuming your username is `keith` you can add yourself to that group by executing

```
sudo adduser keith dialout
```

restart and try again. everything should be working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Change the device port permission to:

```
chmod a+rw /dev/ttyXXX
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Comment: Add 'sudo'. The command should be: 'sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyXXX'.